# Unshuffle the questions on javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to javascript and I have codes for a survey and the questions are shuffled on each attempt, I want to stop that featureand I can't figure out how.

Here are the codes on my container

```
import React from 'react';
import QuestionPage from '../Pages/QuestionPage';
import axios from "axios";
import env from "../config/env";
import shuffle from 'shuffle-array';

class QuestionContainer extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            questions: []
        };
        this.SubmitQuestion = this.SubmitQuestion.bind(this);
    }
    componentDidMount() {

        axios.get(`${env.url}/api/v1/en/questions?limit=100`).then((res) => {

            let qes = shuffle(res.data.questions.map(a => ({
                questionId: a.question_no,
                question: a.question
            })));
            this.setState({ questions: qes });
        }, (err) => {
            console.log("Question fetch error ", err);
            this.setState({questions:[{
                    questionId: 1,
                    question: 'All'}]})
        });
    }
    SubmitQuestion(userAnswer){
        axios.post(`${env.url}/api/v1/answer`,userAnswer).then((res) => {          
          console.log("Submitting success",res.data);
        }, (err) => {
            console.log("Submitting user answer  ", err);

        });
    }
    render() {
        if(this.state.questions.length === 0 ) return null;
        return (<QuestionPage SubmitQuestion={this.SubmitQuestion} 
            questions={this.state.questions} />);
    }
}
export default QuestionContainer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

```
import React from 'react';
import QuestionPage from '../Pages/QuestionPage';
import axios from "axios";
import env from "../config/env";

class QuestionContainer extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            questions: []
        };
        this.SubmitQuestion = this.SubmitQuestion.bind(this);
    }
    componentDidMount() {

        axios.get(`${env.url}/api/v1/en/questions?limit=100`).then((res) => {
            let qes = res.data.questions; 
            this.setState({ questions: qes });
        }, (err) => {
            console.log("Question fetch error ", err);
            this.setState({questions:[{
                    questionId: 1,
                    question: 'All'}]})
        });
    }
    SubmitQuestion(userAnswer){
        axios.post(`${env.url}/api/v1/answer`,userAnswer).then((res) => {          
          console.log("Submitting success",res.data);
        }, (err) => {
            console.log("Submitting user answer  ", err);

        });
    }
    render() {
        if(this.state.questions.length === 0 ) return null;
        return (<QuestionPage SubmitQuestion={this.SubmitQuestion} 
            questions={this.state.questions} />);
    }
}
export default QuestionContainer;
```

Comment: It worked but for some reason my submit button stopped working, any thoughts?